# Game design: organizing object arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist

To learn Java, I am making a classic "fly around in space" 2d game. Besides the player object, numerous enemies/obstacles (scavengers, hunters, comets, asteroids) exist, each with their own class that extends a GameObject class. As there can be several scavengers, comets etc these are stored in arraylists. However, as each object can interact with each other, there is a lot of looping and duplicate code to have e.g each alien interact according to the objects in the comet arraylist, the asteroid array list and so on.

In my game update function I have:

```
public void update() {

    ArrayList<Rock> rockList = rock.getRockList();
    ArrayList<Scavenger> scavengerList = scavenger.getScavengerList();
    ArrayList<Hunter> hunterList = hunter.getHunterList();
    ....
    npc.update(player, scavengerList, hunterList, rockList);
    ...
```

}

and in my NPC class (which extends the GameObject class)

```
public void update(Player player, ArrayList<Scavenger> scavengerList, ArrayList<Hunter> hunterList, ArrayList<Rock> rockList) {

    for(int i = 0; i < scavengerList.size(); i++) {         
        scavengerList.get(i).update(player,scavengerList, ,hunterList rockList);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < hunterList.size(); i++) {            
        hunterList.get(i).update(player,scavengerList, hunterList, rockList);
    }
...
}
```

And finally I have an update function in my scavenger class, my hunter class etc such as

```
public class Hunter extends NPC{
...
public void update(Player player,ArrayList<Scavenger> scavengerList, ArrayList<Hunter> hunterList, ArrayList<Rock> rockList) {
"update all hunter objects according to the player, scavengers, rocks etc"
}
```

This approach seems to be rather cumbersome and as more classes are created the number or arraylists that needs to be parsed and looped through are getting out of hand. 
Can anyone recommend a better way of doing this?
I guess the obvious way would be to have one list containing all NPC objects and then keeping track of their class type and update accordingly.
Is this a better way of doing it or can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to pass a `World` instance around? You could basically do `for (updatableThing: updatableThings) { updatableThing.update(world);  }`

Comment: Maybe I do not completely understand(still learning) but that World instance would still hold a list that contains and updates all objects right or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a much better way.

For each type of object in your game, work out the set of behaviours/characteristics it needs to exhibit. These behaviours should be defined as interfaces. Then the code dealing with the behaviours/characteristics can use the interface without having to know anything at all about the actually class.

For example, if some objects move each turn according to their current velocity and can potential collide with other objects then there might be an interface:

```
public interface Moving {
    void move();
    boolean hasCollided(Shape shape);
    void handleCollision(Collision collision);
}
```

Any class that moves would then implement this interface. The `World` object could then have a `List<Moving> movingObjects` and then use:

```
movingObjects.forEach(Moving::move);
```

in it's `update` method.

To handle collisions after moving you might have something like:

```
List<Collision> collisions = getAllCollisions(movingObjects);
for (Collision collision: collisions) {
    for (Moving element: collision.getCollidingObjects) {
        element.handleCollision(collision);
    }
}
```

If several classes that implement the interface use a similar mechanism to move themselves then you should move that logic into a separate class:

```
class Inertia implements Moving {
    private Velocity velocity;

    @Override
    public void move(Shape shape) {
        velocity.applyTo(shape);
    }

    @Override
    public void applyForceFrom(Position position) {
        velocity.accelerateAwayFrom(position);
    }
}
```

Your world objects can then delegate their moving behaviour to this class:

```
class Asteroid implements Moving {
    private final Inertia inertia;
    private Shape shape = new Circle(radius);

    @Override
    public void move() {
        inertia.move(shape);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasCollided(Shape other) {
        return this.shape.intersects(other);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCollision(Collision collision) {
        intertia.applyForceFrom(collision.getCentreOfMass());
    }
}
```

This might seem an unnecessary indirection but experience has shown that it's worthwhile in the long term. See [Delegation Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) for more details.

You could have several delegates if movements differ per object (e.g. some effected by gravity, some controlled by AI etc.), or a class could apply more than one delegate in its `move` (e.g. gravity and inertia) or a class could implement its own `move` if its behaviour is unique. All of this can happen without `World` needing to know anything at all about the class of the object is is calling `move` on.

As a general rule, try to avoid using `extends` for the purpose of inheriting behaviour from a superclass. Your structure of Hunter extending NPC extending GameObject will be convenient up until the point at which you realise you also want Hunter to extend Enemy or AIControlled or something else. Hard experiences has shown OO coders that these type of hierarchies look sensible and elegant initially but become unmanageable as you add more complicated functionality.

To go even further and hide all details of which objects implement which behaviour interfaces from `World` you might like to look at the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). This would allow the world object to visit all game objects as a mover, then as an AIAgent, then as a user controlled object and so on without ever having to know what they do during the visit (or if they do anything at all). It's very powerful if well applied but it takes a bit of getting used to.

Finally, there's a very common architectural pattern used by game writers called the [Entity Component System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93component%E2%80%93system). If you're just learning Java I'd ignore this for the moment but if you become a serious game developer you'll likely find it's an improvement over the architecture I describe above.

I've obviously left out a lot of detail in the example (such as the definitions of `Shape`, `Circle`, `Position`, `Velocity`, `Collision` etc.) but that's the general idea. There's a lot more to this and it's worth looking for a book or tutorial on object oriented design to look deeper.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer. I can see how this can avoid repeating code in similar classes. However, what if the objects movement depend on each other. Rocks can collide (and thus change direction), the hunter can avoid a rock or pursue the player. That would require that the move function knows about all the objects and calculate movement accordingly. Would the move function know which object called it and then loop through the Moving list, which, as I mentioned in the original post, is basically all my current lists joined into one?

Comment: I'll provide a common model for collisions in my answer to give you an idea how to handle this. A similar model should work for your other examples.

Comment: Ok my answer is getting ridiculously long now. If it's been helpful then please accept it and then ask another question if there's something specific you need help with.